# C# How do you lock columns in a DataGrid on Windows Mobile 5.0?

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework, windows-mobile-5.0

I am trying to freeze columns in a DataGrid in C#. By freezing I mean making the column always visible even when horizontal or vertical scrolling occurs(as in Excel). My target platform is Windows Mobile 5.0 with 2.0 .Net Framework. Is there any easy way to do this?

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: Do you mean prevent columns in the grid from being resized (lock), and/or ensure that particular columns are always visible even when you scroll horizontally (freeze) like Excel can do?

Comment: Sorry for the poor term choice.
I meant how do you freeze columns like Excel?
(edited initial question to clarify better)